# Best practice: Managing android database references between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

How do I handle references between Fragments showing list of data and different threads/classes updating data in the background. Because of this I need to be able to force update from outside of the Fragments via Observer-inf or something similar.

Currently I'm using dummy factory-class to create a new SqlLiteDatabase object, based on my default settings for it.

```
public static SQLiteDatabase initFor(Context context) {
    db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(NAME, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    return db; }
```

Then I call this from each fragment and sets up adapters, the same applies to the data-inserter-threads. To close the db, I override my activity's onDestroy() and call: initFor(this).close(); .

This is very ugly and it fails on orientation change. I'm thinking of SQLiteOpenHelper but I don't know how it will help me.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution regarding this issue?

Comment: Well not really, but a best practice soloution is always appreciated. 
Anyways I ended up letting my Activites extend an abstract class DatabaseActivity that handled the references to the SqlLiteDatabase. I prefer to avoid Singeltons.

Comment: For the clarity of others in the future, then... When your fragments changed, were you using the same queries and cursors, or rebuilding those as well?

Comment: When the fragments data is changed they are notified via Observer-pattern and then they do a requery of the database cursors and updates the views with new adapters.

Comment: I am aware. :) I was just asking what you were doing, so that I didn't provide an answer that was useless. (i.e. doesn't solve this issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access your database on another thread (in a Service) then have this talk to one class (which could be your helper), you then access this helper class through a singleton initialized in a class that extends Application. You can get your Application class from any of your fragments by calling

```
 ((YourApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getGetDatabaseHelper();
```

Comment: Is this still the solution of the time, or should one use Headless Fragments?

Comment: You could use a headless fragment as well. I'd now recommend looking at using a ContentProvider which is easily accessible with `getActivity().getContentResolver()`